# Poetry translation under original text

Tags: parallel-texts

I have a poem which spans across several pages, within an essay. I'm using `memoir` class. I'd like to typeset the poem and its translation under it, while keeping text and translation together.

Is there something like `parallel` or `reledpar` (or some configuration for these packages), but typesetting the material vertically instead of in parallel columns?

Another idea would be to use as an hack a separate unnumbered footnote series, and insert the translation of each stanza as a footnote. `bigfoot` would be my preference, since I use this package for another feature of my text. I had just a quick look at the documentation, but I'm not finding out how to print the custom footnote set *before* the default footnote set.

EDIT: I add a scheme of the desired output; translation is typeset smaller under the poem (please mind that the poem follows on the next pages):
[image]

Comment: Can you draw a quick diagram?  Not following.

Comment: @commonhare Thanks, example added.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following with `memoir` class, hacking the custom footnote series feature:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newfootnoteseries{A}
\newcommand{\versetranslation}[1]{\footnoteA{#1}} % used for poem translation

\newfootnoteseries{B}
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\footnoteB{#1}} % used for standard footnotes

% Style for verse translations
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{} 
\renewcommand{\footfootmarkA}{}
\renewcommand{\foottextfontA}{\small}
\setlength{\skip\footinsA}{10pt} 
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}

\begin{document}

Text with a standard footnote\footnote{The standard footnote} \lipsum[1-3]

\PoemTitle*{Inferno I}
\begin{verse}
Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita\\
mi ritrovai per una selva oscura,\\
ché la diritta via era smarrita.\versetranslation{Midway upon the journey of our life / I found myself within a forest dark, / For the straightforward pathway had been lost.}

Ahi quanto a dir qual era è cosa dura\\
esta selva selvaggia e aspra e forte\\
che nel pensier rinova la paura!\versetranslation{Ah me! how hard a thing it is to say / What was this forest savage, rough, and stern, / Which in the very thought renews the fear.}

Tant' è amara che poco è più morte;\\
ma per trattar del ben ch'i' vi trovai,\\
dirò de l'altre cose ch'i' v'ho scorte.\versetranslation{So bitter is it, death is little more; / But of the good to treat, which there I found, / Speak will I of the other things I saw there.}

\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

In this example the translations are per stanza, but the mechanism could be easily used at verse level.